# How to do this in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, logic

I have an array(list?) in ruby:

```
allRows = ["start","one","two","start","three","four","start","five","six","seven","eight","start","nine","ten"]
```

I need to run a loop on this to get a list that clubs elements from "start" till another "start" is encountered, like the following:

```
listOfRows = [["start","one","two"],["start","three","four"],["start","five","six","seven","eight"],["start","nine","ten"]]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on [`Array#split`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/CoreExtensions/Array/Grouping.html#M000835) from Rails:

```
def group(arr, bookend)
  arr.inject([[]]) do |results, element|
    if (bookend == element)
      results << []
    end
    results.last << element

    results
  end.select { |subarray| subarray.first == bookend } # if the first element wasn't "start", skip everything until the first occurence
end

allRows = ["start","one","two","start","three","four","start","five","six","seven","eight","start","nine","ten"]
listOfRows = group(allRows, "start")
# [["start","one","two"],["start","three","four"],["start","five","six","seven","eight"],["start","nine","ten"]]
```

Comment: Great solution, like it a lot.

One trivial comment: in Ruby, comment are introduced with `#`, not `//`

Comment: @Bryan Oops! I work in PHP all day and wrote this answer at the end of my work day. Nice catch :)

Answer (score 0):

If you can use ActiveSupport (for example, inside Rails):

```
def groups(arr, delim)
  dels = arr.select {|e| == delim }
  objs = arr.split(delim)

  dels.zip(objs).map {|e,objs| [e] + objs }
end
```